# Android studio error Resolve files of :app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath?

Tags: android

I don't know why I keep getting this error. My colleagues work from main branch everyday and so do I. I pull from it too but I'm getting it since last night. Any ideas folks? Also, Just so everyone knows, I tried clean, Build,Make project on Android Studio. Even tried removing build.gradle but it didn't generate new one.

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  5s 228ms
Resolve files of :app:debugCompileClasspath 15ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to kotlin-stdlib-jre7.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.30)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to design.aar (com.android.support:design:27.1.1)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to facebook-login.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.32.0)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to picasso.aar (com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to exifinterface.aar (com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to exifinterface.aar (com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to customtabs.aar (com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to customtabs.aar (com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-messaging.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-auth.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-core.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-analytics.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-iid.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-iid.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-auth-api-phone.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-auth-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to cardview-v7.aar (com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to cardview-v7.aar (com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to drive-sdk-release-0.5.052.aar (project :drive-sdk-release-0.5.052)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to converter-gson.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to retrofit.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to retrofit.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to constraint-layout.aar (com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to dagger.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to butterknife.aar (com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to extensions.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to rxjava2.aar (android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to common-java8.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to SpinnerDatePicker.aar (com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.6)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to joda-time.jar (joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to logging-interceptor.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to analytics.jar (com.flurry.android:analytics:9.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to blurry.aar (jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to HockeySDK.aar (net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.1.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to multidex.aar (com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to javax.annotation.jar (org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to kotlin-stdlib.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.30) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to recyclerview-v7.aar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to animated-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to animated-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to transition.aar (com.android.support:transition:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to butterknife-annotations.jar (com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.6.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to livedata.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to livedata-core.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to livedata-core.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to facebook-core.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.32.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to facebook-common.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.32.0) 11ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to runtime.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to common.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to common.jar (android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to db-framework.aar (android.arch.persistence:db-framework:1.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to db-framework.aar (android.arch.persistence:db-framework:1.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to db.aar (android.arch.persistence:db:1.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to db.aar (android.arch.persistence:db:1.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to db.aar (android.arch.persistence:db:1.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to gson.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to constraint-layout-solver.jar (com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to javax.inject.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to rxjava.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.6)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-messaging-license.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to annotations.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to reactive-streams.jar (org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-analytics-license.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-iid-license.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-basement-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-common-license.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to bolts-android.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to core.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-auth-api-phone-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-auth-base-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-base-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-tasks-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:12.0.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-analytics-impl-license.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to bolts-applinks.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to bolts-tasks.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to okio.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1)    
Resolve files of :app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath 1ms
Execute compile 5s 151ms
Resolve files of :app:debugCompileClasspath 16ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to kotlin-stdlib-jre7.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.30)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to design.aar (com.android.support:design:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to exifinterface.aar (com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to facebook-login.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.32.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to facebook-common.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.32.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to customtabs.aar (com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to customtabs.aar (com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-messaging.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to play-services-auth.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-core.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-analytics.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:12.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to firebase-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to bolts-tasks.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultVariantTransformRegistration@3cd8dea6 to okio.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@6e2890d0 to picasso.aar (com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828)    
Resolve files of :app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath
```